# Going more idiomatic with F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, idioms, function-composition

A very simple example of what I'm trying to do: I know it's possible to write:

```
let myFunc = anotherFunc
```

instead of

```
let myFunc = fun x -> anotherFunc x
```

I've got two functions fDate1, fDate2 - both of type DateTime -> bool. I need to construct a function that takes a date and verifies if any of fDate1, fDate2 returns true. For now I've invented the following expression:

```
let myDateFunc = fun x -> (fDate1 x) || (fDate2 x)
```

Is there a better way of doing these (e.g. using '>>' or high order funcions) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers say, your current approach is fine. What is not said is that **idiomatic style often produces less readable code**. So if you are working in a real project and expect other developers to *understand* your code, it is not recommended to go too far with unnecessary function composition.

However, for purposes of self-education, you may consider the following trick, a bit in FORTH style:

```
// Define helper functions
let tup x = x,x
let untup f (x,y) = f x y
let call2 f g (x,y) = f x, g y

// Use
let myFunc =
    tup
    >> call2 fDate1 fDate2
    >> untup (||)
```

Here, you pass the original value `x` *through a chain of transformations*:

- make a tuple of the same value;
- apply each element of the tuple to corresponding function, obtaining a tuple of results;
- "fold" a tuple of booleans with `or` operator to a single value;

There are many drawbacks with this approach, including that *both* of `fDate1` and `fDate2` will be evaluated while it may not be necessary, extra tuples created degrading performance, and more.

Comment: "Idiomatic" does not necessarily mean the style that uses the language's feature to the extreme; rather, it's the style most common among users of the language. I'd say that your example here looks more like idiomatic Haskell (if you invert the direction of the composition operators), whereas Tomas's code is more idiomatic F#.

Comment: One day, I'd like to understand why people think that "idiomatic" means point-free Haskell :-)

Comment: Well, hmmm... idiomatic Haskell would look more like `myFunc f g = (||) <$> f <*> g` (using Applicatives). Not too point-free, but also not too point-ful ;)

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is anything non-idiomatic with your code. In my opinion, one of the strong points about F# is that you can use it to write simple and easy-to-understand code. From that perspective, nothing could be simpler than writing just:

```
let myDateFunc x = fDate1 x || fDate2 x
```

If you had more functions than just two, then it might make sense to write something like:

```
let dateChecks = [ fDate1; fDate2 ]
let myDateFunc x = dateChecks |> Seq.exists (fun f -> f x)
```

But again, this only makes sense when you actually need to use a larger number of checks or when you are adding checks often. Unnecessary abstraction is also a bad thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a choice combinator:

```
let (<|>) f g = fun x -> f x || g x

let myDateFunc = fDate1 <|> fDate2
```

In general, you should use *explicit* function arguments. The elaborated form of `myDateFunc` can be written as:

```
let myDateFunc x = fDate1 x || fDate2 x
```